# TicTacToe Minimax algorithm

Tags: python

I wrote a Tic Tac Toe game and I tried to implement the minimax algorithm for the AI but I have some problems with the code.

The problem is that it dosen't choose the move that will result in a victory for AI, and it chooses the same move over and over again if you play in a specific way.Basically, the algorithm is broken.

Note: The algorithm is from the Wikipedia pseudo code.

Here is what i managed to do:

```
def MiniMax(self, AI):
    if self.evalWin():
        if AI:
            return 10

        return -10

    if self.evalTie():
        if AI:
            return 0

        return 0

    bestmove = None
    bestMax  = float("-inf")
    bestMin  = float("inf")

    for move in self.getAvailableMoves():
        if AI:
            self.makeMove(move, self.opponent)

            score = self.MiniMax(False)

            bst = max(bestMax, score[0]) if type(score) == tuple else max(bestMax, score)

            if type(score) == tuple:
                if score[0] >= bst:
                    bestmove = move

            elif type(score) == int:
                if score >= bst:
                    bestmove = move

            self.makeMove(move, "_")
            print(bst, bestmove)

            return bst, bestmove

        else:
            self.makeMove(move, self.player)

            score = self.MiniMax(True)

            bstm = min(bestMin, score[0]) if type(score) == tuple else min(bestMin, score)

            if type(score) == tuple:
                if score[0] >= bstm:
                    bestmove = move

            elif type(score) == int:
                if score >= bstm:
                    bestmove = move

            self.makeMove(move, "_")

            return bstm, bestmove
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem with the code?

Comment: 1. Cut the code down to a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 2. Provide a more useful problem statement than *"have some problems"*.

Comment: You could add a link to the complete code on http://pastebin.com/ / https://gist.github.com/

Comment: [Complete Map of optimal Tic-Tac-Toe Moves](https://xkcd.com/832/).

Answer (score 0):

Tic-Tac-Toe has only 765 different positions. It's easy to make an AI that wins always if it is theoretically possible.